# How to change notation in R

Tags: r

In R, the matrix multiplication is A%*%B. It's really annoying if you deal with a lot of matrices. Is it possible to change the notation to A*B?

Comment: 1- Yes this is possible by simply doing `\`*\` <- \`%*%\``. 2- This **highly** unrecommended and you shouldn't override existing functions. 3- In order to make it permanent (not only for the current session) it will be a bit more involved. 4- This is not the correct site for such question.

Comment: If this is "really annoying" what points lie beyond?

Answer (score 0):

In brief,

1. Create an RStudio addin which inserts "%*%" at the cursor position.
2. Assign a shortkey to it.

See this [tutorial](https://rstudio.github.io/rstudioaddins/) by RStudio.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function to eliminate typing `%*%`

```
f <- function(x, y) {
  x %*% y
}

f(A, B)
```